# pandas export string series without string truncation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have simple code that merges two string series and writes the result to a file

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)

def merge(row):
  return row['labels'] + ' ' + row['text']

fasttext_formatted = label_converted.applymap(str).apply(merge, axis=1)

with open("fasttext_tagged_input", "w") as outfile:
    fasttext_formatted.to_string(outfile, index=False)
```

If `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)` is omitted, the strings are truncated when written to the file. I assume there would be a better way than using a (global) display option like that ― can you suggest one?

(running inside a Jupyter notebook)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`option_context`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.option_context.html).

> **option_context** context manager has been exposed through the top-level API, allowing you to execute code with given option values. Option values are restored automatically when you exit the **with** block:

```
def merge(row):
  return row['labels'] + ' ' + row['text']

with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', -1):
    fasttext_formatted = label_converted.applymap(str).apply(merge, axis=1)

    with open("fasttext_tagged_input", "w") as outfile:
        fasttext_formatted.to_string(outfile, index=False)
```

Also maybe is possible improve it - use [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) + [`Series.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html) and omit `apply`:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', -1):
    #convert all columns to string
    fasttext_formatted = label_converted.astype(str) 
    #concentrate columns to Series new
    new = fasttext_formatted['labels'] + ' ' + fasttext_formatted['text']
    #write Series to csv 
    new.to_csv(fasttext_tagged_input, index=False)
```

Comment: That looks good, but I also thought there'd be a non-display setting. Maybe the conversion and display concerns are just coarsely unified, so thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately I have no another idea. But I like very much  `with` with `display`, because no problem with setting and reseting. Nice weekend!

Comment: I am thinking about `to_csv` function - there is problem with truncating too?